# Pass variable to setTimeout()

Tags: javascript

I would like to do this:

```
var whatever = myfunction;
var time = 200;
setTimeout(whatever, time);

function myfunction() {
    //do something
}
```

It's not working am I am unsure why

Better example:
Here is the html
Html:

```
<div id="example1" class="example-card" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
<div id="example2" class="example-card" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
```

Here is the JS
JS:

```
function example1() {
    $("#example1").css('visibility', 'visible');
}
function example2() {
    $("#example2").css('visibility', 'visible');
}

$(window).on("load", function(){
    var time = 0;
    $('.example-card').each(function() {
        var exampleId = this.id;
        setTimeout(exampleId, time);
        time = time + 200;
    });
});
```

Thanks,

Comment: function is a keyword. Use a different variable name

Comment: `function` is reserved name, so your variable can't be named `function`

Comment: you don't need a variable just pass your function to setTimeout like setTimeout(myfunction, time)

Comment: Sorry that was just a poor use of an example name

Comment: I need it to be a variable because I will have the setTimeout in a loop

Comment: Try declaring your function before assigning it to a variable. I think hoisting would prevent this being an issue, but it's worth discounting

Comment: I've tried declaring it before the setTimeout, it doesn't work

Comment: That works for me.

Comment: the code in the question is working correctly. what is the _actual_ issue? Do you see an error, it runs immediately, does nothing at all....?

Comment: @BACode I think we need a better example. You say this will be called in a loop. Can you provide an example of the loop?

Comment: Ive posted as an answer. See for yourself...

Comment: Does it work on your machine?

Comment: Ive just added a better example

Comment: @JamesLong Ive just added a better example

Comment: That's a completely different question! lol - Anyway, have updated my answer with your new solution. :)

Comment: @Lece Thanks that works! Sorry next time I'll post things exactly how they are, shouldn't assume things I don't know about. Have a great day!

Comment: Not a problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function example1() {
    $("#example1").css('visibility', 'visible');
    console.log("example1");
}

function example2() {
    $("#example2").css('visibility', 'visible');
    console.log("example2");
}

$(window).on("load", function() {
    var time = 0;
    var func = 0;
    $('.example-card').each(function() {
       switch(this.id) {
       case "example1":
           func = example1;
           break;
       case "example2":
           func = example2;
           break;
       default:
           func = 0;
           break;
       }
       if (func) {
           setTimeout(func, time);
           time = time + 2000;
       }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example1" class="example-card" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
<div id="example2" class="example-card" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var whatever = myfunction;
var time = 2000;
setTimeout(whatever, time);

function myfunction() {
    alert("hi");
}
```

Comment: Did you try running your snippet?.

Comment: This invokes myfunction() immediately and passes the (void) return value to setTimeout.

Comment: @Keith yes  thats y i posted, did you try it?

Comment: So how many seconds did you wait for the dialog box to appear?

Comment: That's better.. :)

Comment: @Keith Thanks,accidentally made a function call instead of referring its name

Answer (score 2):

Currently you're calling the string in your code, which is not possible:

```
function test() {
    console.log('Test');
}

var id = 'test';

id(); // Fails, this is the string.
```

You can get the function through `window`, since it's global:

```
window[id](); // Success, this is a function.
```

This works, but is unsafe: you can also call other functions declared in the window. For example if your ID is `alert`, it'll call the alert function.

The best way of doing this is by declaring the functions in an object:

```
var callbacks = {
    test: function() {
        console.log('Test')
    }
};

var id = 'test';

callbacks[id](); // Calls the function in the object
```